# 4Sum in leetcode able to run but failed to be submitted

Tags: python

I am currently working on the leetcode 4sum question

*Given an array nums of n integers and an integer target, are there elements a, b, c, and d in nums such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.
Note:
The solution set must not contain duplicate quadruplets.*

https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/

I am able to run the result and the result was accepted. Yet, when I try to submit it, the following error message appears.

```
KeyError: 0
for combination_n in a2[n]:
Line 24 in fourSum (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().fourSum(param_1, param_2)
Line 61 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 72 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Here is my code

```
import collections

class Solution:
    def fourSum (self, nums, target):

    #all possible combination of any two numbers in the list        
    a2={}        
    # append all combination to a particular value
    # format{value:rank in list, rank in list}
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(1,len(nums)-i):
            if nums[i]+nums[j+i] not in a2:
                a2[nums[i]+nums[j+i]]=[[i,j+i]]
            elif [j+i,i] not in a2[nums[i] + nums[j+i]]:
                a2[nums[i] + nums[j+i]].append([i,j+i])

    final_list=[]
    
    #iterate all possible value of any two items in the list "nums"
    #find all the combination of value to achieve the target
    for sumofa2 in a2:
        n=target-sumofa2
        # find the cooresponding rank in list to achieve the value
        for combination_n in a2[n]:
            for combination_sumofa2 in a2[sumofa2]:
                list = combination_n + combination_sumofa2
                if len(set(list)) == len(list):
                #replace the actual value to the coresponding rank in the list
                    for n,rank in enumerate(list):
                        list[n]=nums[rank]
                        list.sort()
                    #avoid duplication in the list
                    if list not in final_list:
                        final_list.append(list)

    return (final_list)
    print(final_list)
```

May I know what's going on, thank you very much!

Comment: a2 has no 0 key in this case.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean

Comment: @VicentLHKROT, your dictionary `a2` doesn't contain a key `0`, so `a2[0]` throws a [`KeyError`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a bug in the keys of your dictionary for the edge cases, I could not figure it out yet. Most likely the bug is around this line `for j in range(1,len(nums)-i):`.
- Once you'd fix that, you'd most likely get a TLE, because your solution is an order of N ^ 4.
- This'd pass though:

```
class Solution:
    def fourSum(self, nums, target):
        def find_n_sum(lo, hi, target, n, out, res):
            if hi - lo + 1 < n or n < 2 or target < nums[lo] * n or target > nums[hi] * n:
                return

            if n == 2:
                while lo < hi:
                    summation = nums[lo] + nums[hi]
                    if summation == target:
                        res.append(out + [nums[lo], nums[hi]])
                        lo += 1
                        while lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[lo - 1]:
                            lo += 1
                    elif summation < target:
                        lo += 1
                    else:
                        hi -= 1
            else:
                for i in range(lo, hi + 1):
                    if i == lo or (i > lo and nums[i - 1] != nums[i]):
                        find_n_sum(i + 1, hi, target - nums[i], n - 1, out + [nums[i]], res)

        nums.sort()
        res = []
        find_n_sum(0, len(nums) - 1, target, 4, [], res)
        return res
```